# Reloading iframe from another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Can I reload iframe (say __tree_iframe) from another child iframe (__content_iframe)?

Difficulty: IE6/7.

**UPDATE**

Obviosly I should use window.opener and find iframe using it iframes property. Apparently, IE doesn't support window.opener. Any ideas about another way?

Comment: IE does support `window.opener`, but that's for popup windows, not for iframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have trouble accessing the iframe in the parent frame, best give it an ID. Then it should be possible to do a

```
parent.getElementById("frameid").location.reload()
```

if both parent, child and sibling are in the same domain.

Comment: I think he wants to reload sibling iframe, not everything.