# How to pass a value from one frame and receive in another frame in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, frames

I have 2 content pages and I use these 2 pages in a third page as frames in 50% 50% ratio.

I want a TextBox value from Left frame to be transferred to the right frame on a button click.

If I use `session` and try to receive the session value in the 2nd web page(which is the right frame) it won't work because the right frame which is actually a content page will never be invoked.

Please, can someone give me the correct and best way to solve this problem.

Comment: My first reaction is "don't use frames".  Unless you have a really, REALLY good reason for them, don't.  Next, content pages are used in conjunction with a masterpage and can use session variables easily.  What do you mean by it won't work because it "is actually a content page will never be invoked"?  Furthermore, everyone needs their answer "urgently".  It's kind of rude to assume otherwise.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am assuming you are bound with condition of unable to reload the page in the right frame? If it can be reloaded then session or possibly cookie can work. Example to load from iframe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477177/reloading-iframe-from-another-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an event in frame one and make frame 2 have an event handler. On each action in frame 1 you can respond in frame 2.

You can transfer data using a custom class that inherits from EventArgs.

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
// add fields and constructor here
// initialize the fields in the constructor
}
```